# Oracle SQL error - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.EMP_JOB_FK) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

Im new to Oracle SQL, I downloaded the Oracle SQL developer and it came with some pre-programmed tables as you may know. So I picked (Employees) table to practice my Insert statement on. I run the script below and I get an error, the scrip is

```sql
Insert into Employees

Values(1000,'Anouar','Seljouki','Seljouki84@gmail.com',0662777081,to_date('19-03-2012',
'DD,MM,YYYY'),242,16000,Null,Null,Null);
```

the columns are in the following order :

```
Name            Null?    Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)
```

the error is :

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
> insert into Employees
> values(1000,'Anouar','Seljouki','Seljouki84@gmail.com',0662777081,to_date('19-03-12' , 'DD,MM,YY')
> ,242,16000,Null,Null,Null)
>
> Error report -
> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.EMP_JOB_FK) violated - parent key not found

Comment: *"Im new to Oracle SQL, I downloaded the Oracle SQL developer"* Then why tag 2 complete different RDBMS as well..? Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: You've tagged 3 completely different RDBMS? Please only tag the one of interest. Also check out the code formatting function of the editor.

Comment: what RDBMS should I have taggged ? I assume you refer to "Mysql,sql-server,Oracle" tags I have tagged ?

Comment: The error message is telling you what the issue is. The JOB_ID column is a foreign key, pointing to the JOBS table. You cannot insert a row in EMPLOYEES, with a job id that doesn't already exist in the JOBS table. If this is an entirely new job (which didn't exist before in these tables), you must create it in the JOBS table first, then use it in an INSERT into EMPLOYEES. Note that this was a PERFECT test of the INSERT statement: you learned something from it. This is exactly the kind of tests you want to have when you learn something new.

Comment: Tags: yes, `oracle` is the correct tag. Your question has nothing to do with MySQL or SQL Server. Often this website assigns tags to your post automatically, and almost always it gets them wrong; even if YOU did not put them there, you can certainly remove them.

Comment: True, Mysql or SQL server is not oracle SQL. my bad, thanks for your feedback

Comment: One other clarification. You said "I downloaded the Oracle SQL developer and it came with some pre-programmed tables as you may know".  No, SQL Dev does not come with any tables, pre-programmed or otherwise.  It doesn't even come with a database. SQL Dev is _just_ a GUI client.  Any database is a completely separate installation.  And even a default installation of the oracle database doesn't come with any tables like EMPLOYEES etc.  Those are part of the sample schema that is a separate creation in the database _after_ the database is created.

Comment: so as I was installing Oracle SQL, I selected the option to create a Database with the Installation. are you saying that these tables come pre-programmed to make the programmer worker easier ? I was also wondering why Oracle comes with so many accounts ? Such as : HR, Scott and more ? one last quest ? how can I vote for a comment that was made here as a good answer ? forgive me if im causing you guys to work

Comment: to avoid headache, I removed the value I had for JOB_ID and replaced it with NULL. however I got another error saying :ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."EMPLOYEES"."JOB_ID"). why is that ?

Comment: I also tried another way to avoid this Null error, I tried the script below and I got the same error, the script I tried is as follow :

Comment: columns(EMPLOYEE_ID ,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME ,EMAIL ,PHONE_NUMBER ,HIRE_DATE ,SALARY)
Values(1000,'Anouar','Seljouki','Seljouki84@gmail.com',0662777081,
to_date('19-03-2012' , 'DD,MM,YYYY'),16000);

Comment: you cannot use null because the field in the table probably has a NOT NULL constraint on it.

Comment: `NOT NULL` in `JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)` tells you that the job_id is mandatory. Each employee must have a job.

Comment: On a side note: While it is possible to specify a date like this: `to_date('19-03-12' , 'DD,MM,YY')`, it is better never to use two-digit years, but always four-digit years. Much better even is it not to use a string and a function that converts this to a date at all, but use a **date literal** right away. A date literal looks like this: `DATE '2012-03-19'` (i.e. the keyword DATE followed by a string in the format yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: Another side note: If this is your real email you are showing in your request, I'd change this. Emails made public on the Internet can easily get spammed, or so I assume.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the "integrity constraint violated" message is that the value of 242 you're trying to put into the JOB_ID field does not also exist in the table which is referred to in the constraint `HR.EMP_JOB_FK`. You'll have to look at that constraint to figure out what table it's referencing.